What difference between the truth of a conditional* and its logical validity?
I am confused . . . Here is a remark on the "classical analysis" of the implication:

On the classical analysis, logical implication is the same, not as the truth of a conditional statement, but as the validity of one. - Curtis Franks, The Deduction Theorem (Before and After Herbrand)

The validity of a conditional? Presumably, this means the logical validity of the conditional, but what is that?! I knew of the logical validity of an argument, not that of a conditional.
Curtis Franks is one of two editors-in-chief of the Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic, so I will assume that he understands what he is talking about, but me, I don't understand what he says!
I presume that "classical analysis" here refers to the so-misleadingly called Classical Logic (it is of course neither "classical" nor "logic"), an expression which only refers to the theory based on Frege's idea, adopted by Russell, that the implication A implies B is logically equivalent to "not A or B".
I also presume but maybe I'm wrong that this is not meant to say that conditionals are neither true nor false . . . So, if they are not only either true or false but now also logically valid or invalid, what is the difference between the truth of a conditional and its logical validity? When is it that a conditional is true, but not, somehow, logically valid, or vice versa?
Or is it just Franks who misspoke somewhat?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

From the previous page:"The classical propositional validities are the formulas that receive the value T on every interpretation... Γ ⊨ B is the classical analysis of the claim that, taken jointly, the formulas in Γ logically imply the formula B." So Franks' "validity" means "tautology", and his "implication" means (semantic) "entailment". The OP quoted remark is the rephrasing of the deduction meta-theorem, "Γ, A ⊨ B if and only if Γ ⊨ A ⊃ B", which it follows. In other words, entailment of B by A is "the same" as A ⊃ B being a tautology, rather than just being true.

See Valid formula: "A formula of a formal language is a valid formula if and only if it is true under every possible interpretation of the language. In propositional logic, they are tautologies."
Example: p → p.
For reference, see a ML textbook whatever: e.g. van Dalen.
With "logical implication" the author means logical consequence: Γ⊨B.
Thus, what the author means is that: Γ,A ⊨ B IFF Γ ⊨A → B, and this is exactly the Deduction Theorem.

This example is on page 2: "If you arrive at my house before 3pm, then I will give you a ride to the concert." On many* analyses, the sentence could be true without being logically valid. In fact, if it were logically valid, then there would be no point in uttering it, because "you could just do some logic in private and determine that since [a ride] is what you want and [a ride] is implied by [timely arrival], you need only worry yourself with [timely arrival], knowing that if you succeed, [a ride] is automatic." Clearly it isn't. But it could still be true and therefore worth saying.
*On other analyses, such as Philip Rhinelander's and possibly Ramsey's and Adams's, the sentence isn't the sort of thing that can be true: It is a conditional statement rather than a statement of a conditional.

"the sentence isn't the sort of thing that can be true" Why is that? It seems uncontroversial that it is either true or false that if A is true, then B is true, so the conditional statement "if A, then B" is indeed either true or false, whether or not we know it is.

In Quine's old book Methods of Logic he attributes this idea to Rhinelander: The indicative mood conditional "If A, then B" is not a statement of a conditionally structured proposition, but rather the conditional statement of B. This is similar to the so-called suppositional analysis of indicative mood conditionals introduced by Ramsey and advocated for by Adams.

On this "suppositional" analysis, such conditionals are equivalent to a claim like "the probability of B given A is >95%." Denote this claim A|B and ask: Does A⊃B (the material conditional equivalent to classical "not A or B") imply A|B? It is possible to derive a contradiction from the assumption that it does as well as from the assumption that it does not. So A⊃B neither implies nor fails to imply A|B. Conclusion: A|B is not the sort of thing that stands in entailment relationships with propositions, i.e., is not a proposition itself.

A great discussion of this result, originally proved by David Lewis but beautifully reworked by Edgington herself, is in section 3.1 or Dorothy Edgington's SEP article on indicative mood conditionals.

Thanks, this is really helpful.

"Conclusion: A|B is not the sort of thing that stands in entailment relationships with propositions, i.e., is not a proposition itself." What do you think would be the importance of proving that probabilities just follow from the logic of the conditional?
